# Have an SSD and HDD as the same filesystem and overflow from one to the other?

Tags: filesystems, disk, block-device, device-mapper

Is it possible in Linux (specifically OpenSUSE) to have an SSD and a HDD set up in such a way that they appear as a single filesystem, yet data is always written to the SSD until full, and then "overflow" to the HDD?

Comment: https://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/ might be the sort of thing to look into

Answer (score 1):

Setting up RAID in Linear Mode should achieve what you are looking for. You can find more information [here](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup)

Comment: That would not guarantee that the SSD portion is written first.

Comment: the [wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/What_is_RAID_and_why_should_you_want_it%3F#Linear_mode) entry seems to suggest that there is an order to the disk writes.

Comment: You are right; the first disk in the RAID array will have the lowest block addresses (or something to that effect). However, the filesystem that will be on top of the array is unlikely to guarantee that files are then written in increasing address order. I also suspect that the asker wants a more complex scheme than what they asked.